# Acoustic characteristics of thoracic diaphragm

Tags: imaging, ultrasound, mri

I am looking for any kind of information about the acoustic characteristics of the thoracic diaphragm. In particular, I'm looking for characteristics which will allow to differentiate it from other muscles using ultrasound, MRI, CT, etc.

References to the literature are especially welcome.

Comment: One identifies the diaphragm on ultrasound/CT by thinking about the anatomy and appearance (e.g. on ultrasound it's a thin hyperechoic structure between the liver and lungs). I'm a bit unsure what you're asking as unless you get close to the body wall there's not many other muscles in that area to confuse it with.